# How do I manage assets in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, assets

OK, so I'm starting a new project using Rails 3.1 and I'm new to CoffeeScript.

Anyway, I like the idea of having asset files representing controllers but what if I only want the JS to render when the controller is called?

For example, I have a controller called `Game`.  In my `games.js.coffee` file, I put some code in there and it's called for every page request.  Even pages that have nothing to do with `Games`.

In `Rails 3.0.7`, what I would do is put a `yield(:js)` in the application erb file and then call `content_for(:js)` in my `Games#action` view.  That way, only the js that was needed for that controller was loaded.

Or, am I going about this the wrong way?  Is it better to have **ALL** js code loaded and cached for every page request to improve performance?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it better to have ALL js code loaded and cached for every page request to improve performance?

Basically, the Rails team decided that the answer is usually "yes." Most sites work best with just a single (minified) JS file, which you get by default in Rails 3.1. That way, once the user has accessed a single page of your site, all other pages will load quickly, since all the JS has been cached.

If your site has a *huge* amount of JS (think Facebook), then I'd suggest architecting your site to load rarely-used JS code asynchronously, using a library like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). Otherwise, I wouldn't bother loading different code under different controllers; it's a lot of extra work for a marginal benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin, I think it solves your problem: https://github.com/snitko/specific_assets